# onChange event on input returns 'Cannot read property search of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React components, one parent component and one child component. They are both in a separate file and the code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import axios from "axios/index";

var processedQuery;
var url = 'https://some-url-api.com/q=';

class MainContent extends Component {
    state = {
        results: '',
        query: ''
    }

    getData = () => {
        axios.get(url + processedQuery)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                this.setState({
                    results: data
                })
            })
    }

    handleInputChange = () => {
        processedQuery = this.search.value.split(' ').join('+');
        this.setState({
                query: processedQuery
            }, () => {
                this.getData();
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-content">
                <SearchBar handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainContent;
```

And the child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-content__search-bar">
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search for..."
                        onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Everything worked fine while the `getData` and `handleInputChange` functions were inside of the child component. However, when i moved them to the parent component and try to type something in the input, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

I went through the code multiple times and can't really find what I'm missing. Any help?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling the function onChange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parent component should take the new value as a parameter:

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    processedQuery = event.target.value.split(' ').join('+');
    // ...
}
```

I'd argue that the child should actually pass the value in (not the event).

```
onChange={event => this.props.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}
```

And the parent can do:

```
handleInputChange = (searchTerm) => {
    processedQuery = searchTerm.split(' ').join('+');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Frank, but unfortunately the issue still persists...

Comment: Is anything getting passed to `handleInputChange`?

Comment: I did a `console.log(searchTerm)` at the start of `handleInputChange`, but i get nothing logged in dev tools. Seems like nothing is being passed..

Comment: Also, I removed everything inside of `handleInputChange` and just left the `console.log`. Still nothing..

Comment: Maybe you can try to reproduce the issue on something like StackBlitz. I can't seem to spot anything.

Comment: I posted the same exact code on StackBlitz and it works perfectly. I'm really not sure what is going on at the moment, but will update this thread if I manage to fix it. In the meanwhile, I'm accepting your answer as correct since it solved the issue as showed on StackBlitz.